# Django project is creating into C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3 by default

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am putting "django-admin startproject mysite". Project is creating in the folder of C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3 by default instate of desire folder. Please help me out.

pip install django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running on a PC that has Comodo managed by devops. I cannot control the settings without them being approved and implemented by someone else. But there is probably a folder where you can do this work if you are able to move to it.

For me, it was C:\ProgramData\Shared Space

**This is a hidden directory. Use at your own risk!**

***Summary:*** Comodo -> Settings -> Containment -> (Do not virtualize access to) the Specified files folders -> Expand Shared Spaces and see where it points.

**Details:**
In Comodo, if you open up the program from the taskbar, and then click on settings. You will see tabs on the left. Click on the one labeled "Containment."

Hopefully a "Shared Space" has been made available for you to put this sort of work in that will not be virtualized / quarantined.

Locate "Do not virtualize access to the specified files/folders" Click on the link in that sentence.

A dialog will open up that shows the shared spaces that have been defined. Expand that list and you will see where you can put files / folders that Comodo will ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with a C# project on Windows machine.

Try these steps if you have Comodo antivirus installed:

1. Open the comodo, select "Unblock Applications"
2. Find your installer and unblock it.
   If you have any other antivirus installed, I am not sure if the above steps work but there is no harm in trying.